# getIn() not traversing an Immutable structure

Tags: immutable.js

I have an **OrderedMap** called "firebase" from the *immutable-js* library which has three leaf nodes:

[image]

but then I'd expect to be able to inspect the ordered map at `firebase.auth` with:

```
newValue.getIn(['firebase', 'auth'])
```

But that doesn't work:

[image]

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your `auth` is an OrderedMap, but it seems that your `firebase` is a simple JavaScript object, not an Immutable.js one. Hence why getIn would not work.

`newValue.get('firebase').auth` probably works for you?

Comment: Shoot, I think you're right. I had convinced myself away from that but yeah that comes from combineReducers always producing a standard JS object. Damn. Want to write this as the the answer? I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Sure :) I added a note about the `combineReducers` problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `auth` is an Immutable `OrderedMap`, but it seems that your `firebase` is a simple JavaScript object, not an Immutable.js one. Hence why getIn would not work. Thus `newValue.get('firebase').auth` would suffice.

If you are not using the `redux-immutable` package then you are probably going to have these (and other) issues due to `combineReducers`. However, `combineReducers`  created using redux-immutable uses Immutable.js API to iterate the state so check it out.